# How to display correctly my DataTables table?

Tags: css, datatables

I have created a Datatables table using AJAX, but when I try to render it, the `<tr>` inside the `<tbody>`, are shorter than those in the `<thead>`.

There are 2 pages: the first one is the form and the header of the table, hidden by default. When the user clicks on the search button, it displays the header and loads the table body via AJAX. The result is the following:

[image: Screenshot]

#### style.css

```css
.outcomeResearchTable {
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
}

.outcomeResearchTable th {
  /*padding:1.0rem; */
  width: 100px !important;
  /* border-bottom:1px solid lightgray; */
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.outcomeResearchTable th:first-of-type {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 80px !important;
}

.outcomeResearchTable th:last-of-type {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 80px !important;
}

#OUTCOME_RESEARCH_TABLE thead {
  display: none;
}

.outcomeResearchTable td {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100px;
}

.outcomeResearchTable td:first-of-type {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 80px !important;
}

.outcomeResearchTable td:last-of-type {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 80px !important;
}
```

#### page1.php

```php
<td colspan="2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="assetSearch();" tabindex="4">Ricerca</button>
  <?php
    echo "<table id=\"OUTCOME_RESEARCH_TABLE\"  class=\"display outcomeResearchTable\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">\n";
      echo "<thead>\n";
        echo "<tr>\n";
          echo "<th>IDConfig</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Nome</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Tipo</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Stato</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Ambiente</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Aggregatore</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Locazione</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Modello</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Contratto</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Valida Dal</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Valida Al</th>\n";
          echo "<th>Dettagli</th>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
      echo "</thead>\n";
    echo "</table><br />\n";
  ?>
</td>
```

#### assePageScript.js

```js
function assetSearch() {
  var validation = checkForSelectedFields();

  if (validation == "KO") {
    return;
  }

  var arrForm = [];

  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("name").value); // 0
  //arrForm.push(document.getElementById("idConfig").value);
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("serialNumber").value); // 1
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("tipo").value); // 2
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("ambiente").value); // 3
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("modello").value); // 4
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("locazione").value); // 5
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("vendor").value); // 6
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("gruppo").value); // 7
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("stato").value); // 8
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("classe").value); // 9
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("securityLevel").value); // 10
  arrForm.push(document.getElementById("aggregatore").value); // 11

  $.ajax({
    url: "asset_GestAsset.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      "fieldValue": JSON.stringify(arrForm)
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var outcomeResearchTable = document.getElementById("OUTCOME_RESEARCH_TABLE");

      outcomeResearchTable.style.display = "flex";

      var outComeRT = $('#OUTCOME_RESEARCH_TABLE').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "dom": 'ltipr',
        "data": data,
        "destroy": true,
        "pageLength": 100,
        "scrollY": 400,
        "scrollX": true,
        "ordering": true
      });
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert("Errore " + err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: probably something to do with this line `outcomeResearchTable.style.display = "flex";`, why you changing the display of the table?

Comment: @zgood because it is hidden as you can see in style.css. When the user click on "Ricerca" button, it shows the table and I set display flex for a responsive design

Comment: You should set it to `display: table;` because thats what datatables expects. Datatables has a [responsive extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) if you want it responsive.